# Как расставить знаки препинания в моём предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Стать на сторону закона вы можете предав мафию и придя в полицейское управление.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Стать на сторону закона вы можете, / **предав мафию и придя в полицейское управление.***

Запятая ставится **по обычным правилам** обособления двух распространенных обстоятельств со значением условия, которые выражены **деепричастными оборотами** и соединены одиночным союзом И.

**Особенность** предложения в том,  что пауза здесь не четко обозначена, но запятая ставится по правилам (грамматический принцип в пунктуации).

В то же время здесь нет наречного значения деепричастий, и они обозначают добавочное действие.

Comment: Я что-то не совсем вас понял. Здесь ведь нет причастных оборотов.

Comment: Извините, исправила.

Comment: Пауза будет считаться грамматической и обозначаться по правилам запятой, но по длительности ее нельзя назвать подчеркнутой (она короче). Это связано с тем, что в первой части предложения нет четкого ударения, мы как бы сразу переходим ко второй части со значением условия. Этот момент может вызвать у пользователей определенные затруднения при постановке запятой.

Comment: А почему нет наречного значения? *Как можете стать? Предав мафию и придя в полицейское управление.* Здесь как бы образ действия (*стать таким образом*). Ну или тесная связь, как в "стал как новый". Не так ли?

Comment: Семантически да, ближе к образу действия, но по грамматике не пройдет ввиду распространенности.  Поэтому я здесь говорю о  грамматическом принципе в пунктуации. Почему образ действия?  Надо подчеркнуть условие при наличии "можете", особенно в сложном предложении. Сравнить: Сделать так можно предав себЯ, поэтому не нАдо так делать.

Comment: Ну, в исходном тоже так: *Стать на сторону закона вы можете(,) предав мАфию и придя в полицейское управлЕние.* Грамматика вроде бы не запрещает распространённые. Помните у Розенталя "*Это упражнение делают стоя на вытянутых носках*"? Добавим элемент: *Это упражнение делают стоя на вытянутых носках и держа ноги на ширине плеч.* По модели исходного: *Это упражнение можно делать стоя на вытянутых носках.* Пунктуация не меняется. В данной теме длина не влияет на пунктуацию и ударения, здесь важен смысл.

Comment: Здесь еще два оборота, что осложняет ситуацию.  Запись текста на письме тоже надо сделать понятной (по части грамматики).